# Check for admin permissions in Yesod using database

Tags: haskell, yesod, hamlet

I'm trying to implement the `isAdmin` function in a similar fashion to [these Yesod book examples](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/blog-example-advanced). The problem is that I want to keep my 'admin' emails in the database, but when I make a database query, `isAdmin` loses its purity, so I have to return `Handler-something IO Bool` instead of just `Bool`. Now, this scraps the very nice syntax sugar in hamlet that allows to do so:

```
$if isAdmin
    <p ...
```

Is there a way to still have a pure `isAdmin` function even if I make a call to the database (I seriously doubt that... by the way, I don't want to pass any parameters to `isAdmin`)? Or maybe I could still use the `$if` syntax with the impure function?

P.S.: Currently, I am using a hack in the handler module:

```
isadmin <- isAdmin
```

So, I can write in the hamlet corresponding to that handler:

```
$if isadmin
```

But it is not universal and I like the first method more.

Comment: "a pure `isAdmin` function" -- Terminology nitpicking: something that doesn't take arguments isn't a function. A better wording would be "a pure `isAdmin` value". If you were talking about the monadic `isAdmin` you actually have, you could also say "an `isAdmin` computation".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*N.B.: I don't actually know Yesod; this answer is based on general Haskell practice.*

> Is there a way to still have a pure isAdmin function even if I make a call to the database (I seriously doubt that

It is not possible indeed. Access to an external database must, in one way or another, live in `IO`; there is no way around it.

> Currently, I am using a hack in the handler module:
>
> `isadmin <- isAdmin`
>
> So, I can write in the hamlet corresponding to that handler:
>
> `$if isadmin`

That is not a hack; it is one of the standard ways of using the result from a monadic computation. In fact, in the Yesod book page you linked to, right before the `isAdmin` example you mentioned, there is a snippet that runs a database query and uses the result with `$if` in a very similar way to what you are doing now:

```
getBlogR :: Handler Html
getBlogR = do
    -- etc.
    entries <- runDB $ selectList [] [Desc EntryPosted]
    -- etc.
$if null entries
    -- etc.
```

P.S.:

> N.B.: I don't want to pass any parameters to isAdmin

I wonder why you don't want to do so. Perhaps it is because your only need to check whether a single specific user is an admin. In that case, you should consider renaming your computation to `isCurrentUserAdmin` (or whatever makes sense in your use case). Seeing a name like `isAdmin` begs the question  "*who* is an admin?", and so it is rather surprising that something with that name doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: duplode, thanks for your answer. Well, it's just like I thought :)
As for why I called my approach a hack, is that isAdmin is supposed to be a kind of "static helper function", if you allow me this metaphor from Java. But with my current approach, I have to initialize a variable in every Handler that corresponds to the hamlet file I wish to use it in.

Concerning the function name, I just took what was written in the article I cited :)

Comment: I'll let it hang for a day or so in case someone else has an idea of how to organize this in yesod. If not, I'll be accepting your answer :)

Comment: @Igor The moral equivalent to `isadmin <- isAdmin` with a static method in Java would be something like `bool isadmin = SomeClass.isAdmin();` (i.e. calling the static method somewhere and stroring the result in a local variable). If I'm right in thinking you wouldn't bat an eyelid when doing the latter in Java, then using `<-` to give local names to values when using monads should feel just as natural.